# How do I get a certain list item value in Selenium inside a div class, when there are multiple div with the same class?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I would like to extract the number 7011 from this website: https://www.cpbl.com.tw/box?year=2013&KindCode=A&gameSno=54
Those source HTML around the area I wish to extract it from is this:

```
<div class="GameNote"><ul><li><span>時間</span>03:28</li> <li><span>觀眾</span>7011</li></ul>
```

There are more than one div with class "GameNote," and when I tried the following, it only gave me the first div with that class, and not the one that I wanted:

```
driver = wd.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
driver.get('https://www.cpbl.com.tw/box?year=2013&KindCode=A&gameSno=54')
att = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='GameNote']")
tab_att=att.get_attribute('innerHTML')
attendance=read_html(tab_att)
driver.close()
```

I also need help getting the list items.

Thanks.

**Python Version:** 3.7.6
**Spyder Version:** 4.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out. `driver.find_elements_by_xpath(""//div[@class='GameNote']")` instead of  `driver.find_element_by_xpath(""//div[@class='GameNote']")`

Add the "s."